# Sorting a specific MultiDimensional Array in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting

I'm trying to sort specific data from my Broker to a format that i can paste into GoogleSheets (which then does some calculations for logging it in a Journal). Being new to ruby (less than 20 hrs experience) so excuse any bad formatting or logical errors.

Able to get 95% of required output, just want to Sort it based on 'Date' column.

Result- https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5lQz.png

Input File - https://www.dropbox.com/s/xhtr6cda95c2i7f/AI.txt?dl=0

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

```
AllItems = Array.new()
#filename="AI.txt"

def read_transcations(filename)
    lines=open(filename)
    transaction = Array.new
    lines.each do |record| transaction.push(record) end
        transaction.each do |value| output=value.split("|")
                AllItems.push(output)
    end
    puts
    return AllItems
end #end of main function

def main
    answer = read_transcations("AI.txt")

    t_tradeType = 0, t_orderID = 1, t_ticker = 2, t_ticker_description = 3, t_exchange = 4,
    t_action = 5, t_action_tag = 6, t_date = 7, t_time = 8, t_currency = 9, t_quantity = 10,
    t_unknown = 11, t_price = 12, t_total = 13, t_comission = 14, t_unknown2 = 15

    i=0 ;t_count=(answer.length-1)
    puts "There are total #{t_count} transactions."
    puts "Date\t\t    Ticker\tIn \t\tOut \tTime_in\t\tTime_out\tComission\n\
------------------------------------------------------------------------"
    t_count.times do |x|
    if answer[x][t_ticker] == answer[x+1][t_ticker]
            #Buy/Sell/Quantity
            buy=answer[x][t_price].to_f ; sell=answer[i+1][t_price].to_f ; qty=answer[x][t_quantity].to_f
            #Comission
            comm = (((answer[x][t_comission]).to_f)+(((answer[x+1][t_comission]).to_f))).abs
            #Profit/Loss
            gain = (((sell-buy)*qty)-comm).round(2)
            if answer[x][t_action] == "SELLTOPEN"
                gain = gain-(gain*2)
            end
            #Time In and Time Out
            require 'time'
            t_in = Time.parse(answer[x][t_time]) ; t_out = Time.parse(answer[x+1][t_time])
            time_diff=((t_out-t_in)/60.to_i).round(2)

            #Date
            require 'date'
            p_date = Date.parse(answer[x][t_date])
            #OutPut for GoogleSheets
            puts "#{p_date}  \t#{answer[x][t_ticker]}  \t#{buy.round(3)} \t#{sell.round(3)} \t#{answer[x][t_time]} \t#{answer[x+1][t_time]} \t#{comm.round(2)}"
            #Interactive Standard output
            #puts "#{x+1}. Ticker #{answer[x][t_ticker]} -> Date = #{answer[x][t_date]}, Comm = #{comm.round(2)} Duration = #{time_diff} Min, P/L = $#{gain},"
    end
    i=i+1;
    end

end #End of main
main
```

---

Comment: This code snippet is kinda interesting. Though it would help others to understand what's going on, if you sticked to basic Ruby guidelines (80 characters per line, 1 command per line, requirements on top ....)

Comment: Would surely keep that in mind for future work. I'd just started experimenting with Ruby and quickly wrote the snippet.
Didn't knew much about those guidelines then, but now i know about it.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sortintg multi-dimensional array - that is array of arrays - in Ruby is no different than sorting array of any other object.

```
a.sort { |x,y| y[5] <=> x[5] }
```

or

```
a.sort! { |x,y| y[5] <=> x[5] }
```

where 5 is index o your date column.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following

```
AllItems.sort!{|x,y| x[7] <=> y[7]}
```

after Line 10 solved the problem.
Thanks a lot.